# How to access Response in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, asp.net-web-api

I have the following method:

```
private async Task<IHttpActionResult> UseHttpCache(Func<Task<IHttpActionResult>> operation) {
      IHttpActionResult result = await operation();
      //Add HTTP Headers here...
}
```

But I can't manage to find any reference to a `Response` in the `ControllerContext`.

I could cast the `IHttpActionResult` to an `HttpResponseMessage` and easily set the headers there, but I'm not much of a fan of downcasting an interface to an implementation.

Is there a way I can set the response's headers in an `ApiController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure this works since I cant test it right now, but how about this.

Define your custom action result class that decorates the original result and adds the header values:

```
public class CachedResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly IHttpActionResult _decorated;
    private readonly TimeSpan _maxAge;

    public CachedResult(IHttpActionResult decorated, TimeSpan maxAge)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _maxAge = maxAge;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await _decorated.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            Public = true,
            MaxAge = _maxAge
        };

        return response;
    }
}
```

And then pass in the configuration you want through the constructor. Like so:

```
private async Task<IHttpActionResult> UseHttpCache(Func<Task<IHttpActionResult>> operation)
{
    IHttpActionResult result = await operation();
    var maxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    return new CachedResult(result, maxAge);
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Thanks!